# More contrast for the titles of previously viewed questions

Tags: feature-request, design

I am having a hard time seeing the difference in color between the titles of new and previously-viewed questions on the summary page.  I am requesting that it be increased to match the contrast used on StackOverflow.

Here are title samples from Mathematica.SE, juxtaposed:

[image]

And from StackOverflow, for comparison:

[image]

Comment: Something has happened recently that made me confused. Now certain questions have a bluish background, but they are certainly not the ones that I have viewed previously.

Comment: @István I believe those are questions that have one or more of your *favorite tags*.